# Add one column to all tables in sequelize

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

i would like to add Active column in all of my tables using sequelize in a much shorter way. Currently I am putting it in all of models one by one. 
I am also using mysql as my database.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with [sequelize hooks](https://sequelize.org/v5/manual/hooks.html).

```
sequelize.addHook('beforeDefine', (attributes) => {
  attributes.id = {
    type: new Sequelize.DataTypes.UUID(),
    allowNull: false,
    primaryKey: true,
    defaultValue: Sequelize.DataTypes.UUIDV4,
  };
});
```